# Magic strings for converting DateTime to string Using C#

Tags: c#

I was greeted with a nasty bug today. The task is pretty trivial, all I needed to do is to convert the DateTime object to string in ***"yyyymmdd"*** format. The "yyyymmdd" part was stated in the development doc from the external software vendor. So, I conveniently copied the string from their file and pasted to my code. So I got the next

```
public string GetDateString(DateTime dateTime)
{
    return dateTime.ToString("yyyymmdd");
}
```

Pretty simple. So simple that I didn't feel like to unit test the method. 20 minutes later, when other parts of my component are done. I started the app to check if things went right. Almost immediately I notice some supposed-to-be date field in my web page is displaying **20091511**! This can't be right, there is no 15th month of a year. So, I rushed back to my code to check possible errors. It turns out the that I should have used "yyyyMMdd" instead of "yyyymmdd" when converting DateTime to string.

Admitted, this bug was due to my lack of attention to details. The difference between "mm" and "MM" are cleared stated in all C# references. I still would like to argue that it's pretty easy to overlook the differences if one doesn't work with this kind of tasks everyday.

My question is: Is there a clean(i.e. no magic string) way to do the coverings in one line of code? The`return dateTime.Year + "" + dateTime.Month + "" + dateTime.Day;` code seems to be working but it's too much like hacking.

Update: Looks like the string format way is the best C# can offer. Maybe I am being brain washed, but I still think this kind of programming style belongs to low-level languages such as c.

Comment: What's wrong with format strings?

Comment: I don't actually understand this question.  What is wrong with using .ToString("ddMMyyyy")?

Comment: I have to agree with Mehrdad - this is one of those cases where the right answer is simply to check the details, it might be a pain (HH and hh is worse) but its one of those things you have to do.

Comment: sorry somethings you just need to get wrong before you can get them right!

Comment: What's the difference between *magic* strings and *magic* methods in the BCL?

Comment: I think the main lesson to learn here - is that you should not have chosen to cheat and skip the unit tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String.Format("{0:0000}{1:00}{2:00}", dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day);
```

You could use this instead, I prefer the terse format though. Instead of 00 you can also use MM for specific month formatting (like in `DateTime.ToString()`).

Answer (score 5):

See here: [.NET Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: I did read the doc,except I wasn't patient enough to read every line :( . That's how I screwed up.

Answer (score 1):

```
return dateTime.Year.ToString() + dateTime.Month + dateTime.Day;
```

You don't need to keep adding empty strings, string+number returns string already and addition is interpreted from left to right.

Do note that that line doesn't return what you think it does, what you really want is:

```
return dateTime.Year.ToString("0000") + dateTime.Month.ToString("00") 
    + dateTime.Day.ToString("00");
```

Comment: This'll create issues with certain dates.

e.g. For 12th January 2009, it'll return :-

2009112

Now, is that 12th January 2009 or 2nd November 2009?

Comment: @Wei Ma - that's why people get paid to be programmers, to deal with this stuff...

Comment: No it won't, the `00` format says the numbers will be padded with 0's as needed. And yes, they are "magic strings", but I thought you were only concerned by the `DateTime` ones? You really should limit your reinventing the wheel, especially with this kind of stuff.

Comment: Yes, this kind of magic strings are better than "mm", "MM", "hh", and "HH". But it's still not what I am looking for. Maybe I am pushing it too much.

Answer (score 1):

If that format string bugs you that much, at least make sure it is in one place. Encapsulate it e.g. in an extension method:

```
public string ToMyAppsPrefferedFormat(this DateTime date) {
  return date.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
}
```

Then you can say `date.ToMyAppsPrefferedFormat()`